# Adding a parameter to url javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to add a parameter to url. Here problem is when I click a tag `history.pushState` is working but after removing parameter. Firstly, `history.pushState` is changing to `/general-info-21,2231-44,333` after url changing to `/general-info`. How can I solve?

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/general-info" data-desc="general-info" onclick="dataInfo($event)">General Info</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
function dataInfo($event){
    var desc = $($event.target).attr("data-desc");
    lat="21,2231";
    lng="44,333";
    history.pushState(null, null, desc + "-" + lat + "-" + lng);  
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it hapens, because the `a` tag does what it should. In your function you can try to disable the default behaviour using `$event.preventDefault();` at the top of the handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just put here the possible solutions.

**Way 1.** You can disable the default behaviour of the tag `a` using `$event.preventDefault();` in your handler.

**Way 2.** You can set `href="#"` instead of `href="/general-info"` and it will not take you to another route

Comment: I have to use first way for seo. Thanks.

Comment: Nice choice. Happy to help!